# Having trouble putting two spans next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have two spans I would like next to each other.

```
<span id = "pic" >
    <img src="me.jpg" id = "prof">
</span>
<span id = "info">
    Lorem ipsum 
</span>
```

My CSS is:

```
#pic{
    width: 40%; 
    float:left; 
    padding-top:6%;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
#info{
    /*width: 40%;*/
    float:right;
    /*padding-left: 75%;*/
    padding-top:16%;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

The second `span` won't float to the right of the first `span` even with `padding-left`, or `margin-left` to 75% when theoretically I should just need 45% to get it to be 5% to the left of the first span.

When I don't have the first span as position fixed (I'd like the picture to stay as the text scrolls) the second span would pop to the top of the first rather than aside it, or  on the bottom starting right next to the bottom where the first line of text aligns to the bottom of the picture.

Comment: You can try to make both Float:left; and position:relative;

Comment: @AlmirM. Check your about me - HTML 3? CSS 5?

Comment: sorry, you can not use position relative after float left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
#pic{
    width: 40%; 
    left:15%;
    padding-top:6%;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
}
#info{
    /*width: 40%;*/
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 16%;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

try it out and let me know if it is what you want

Comment: Why right and top rather than padding and why px over %?

EDIT: I worked with it actually and changed it to 16% and kept `padding-top` and it works! thanks!

Comment: position:absolute is not a very responsive way of positioning elements. Take a look at my answer below to see how it can be done without complicated positioning.

Answer (score 1):

probably late for an answer, however, I'd like to present a technique I came up with to solve such problems that I faced lately...

I had two divs and I wanted to align them beside each others,and I have styled them inline and all these techniques and solutions that I read about here and there, and no matter I do, they display vertically...

The technique I thought of is to put border to the divs and see the space they acquire in the div or whatever they are in...

It turned out that the first div took the whole space horizontally and the other div could not stand beside it... so I reduced the width of the first div and all the solutions there worked out.

So it is not a solution rather that a technique to find a solution... I hope that this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest removing `position: fixed;` since that won't work with the arrangement that it looks like you're trying to achieve. See how it goes.

Comment: I have, but now the second span aligns itself underneath the first rather than being stacked under it.

Comment: I'd suggest removing all the floats. Try getting it just with inline-block. That should be enough.

Comment: Hmm that changed nothing as well

Answer (score 0):

There's only space for 20% or 20vw, so you can put `margin-left/right` or `padding-left/right` together a total of 20% only :

```css
#pic{
    width: 40%; 
    float:left; 
    padding-top:16%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: pink;
}
#info{
    width: 40%;
    float:right;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-top:16%;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id = "pic" >
    <img src="me.jpg" id = "prof">
</span>
<span id = "info">
    Lorem ipsum 
</span>
```

Comment: For some reason my example and that snippet's results don't match. For mine the second `span` really wants to go under the first without `position:fixed` and with, it gets stacked under the first `span`

Answer (score 0):

Percentage-based widths will not always work unless they are contained in a parent which has a known width. Try changing the spans to divs and containing them inside another div:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id = "pic" >
        <img src="me.jpg" id = "prof">
    </div>
    <div id="info">
        Lorem ipsum 
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
}
#pic{
    width: 40%; 
    float: left; 
    padding-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
#info{
    width: 45%
    float: left;
    padding-top: 16%;
    color: white;
}
```

Both sub-divs can float left. The second one stacks to the right of the first. The `br` tells the browser to clear the floats afterwards so any elements created after this will fall below.

Comment: They already are in a div with a width. Just wasn't sure if that was relevant